# How to recognize or tag a database based on database information

Tags: mysql, metadata

Imagen you have 10 MySQL databases (on 3 different servers if that matters).
5 are meant for development purposes and 5 for production purposes.

Then there is some source from which I obtain the connection details of the different databases. Every database contains a connection of its own.

Now in my application, I would like to connect to a database and obtain some kind of information from the database telling me that I am talking to a production or development database.

## question:

Is there some recognizable characteristic thing I could add to a database (maybe a description, tag..., or some metadata thing) which can be obtained from the database to be used in further code execution?

## Thought of solutions:

1. Name the databases with a certain prefix which can be obtained. A downside, it concerns naming of databases :) (we prefer not to, or at least I am currently looking for an alternative solution).
2. Add an additional table in every database which contains a tag 'production' or 'dev'. (Again not a very neat solution I think)

*(Note: I am not an expert in database handling)*

Comment: Tables (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) can have comments it might be idea to use javadoc or phpdoc syntax code and "variables" (annotations) inside the table comments something like `/** @stage = production */`

Comment: And if you do that you can query `information_schema.TABLES` table ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html ) to get easy acces to the used table comment.

Comment: Besides you can easy add comment to a table with `ALTER TABLE <table> COMMENT '<comment>'`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, an Interesting idea. Is that a database-wide property, or table specific?